# linking .so files to ros2 package

Tags: ros2, c++, libraries

Hello Im trying to write a client node using ros2 humble hawksbill distribution.
For the node Im using a shared library for my depth camera.
I have linked the .so file as I would normally do in my CMakelists.txt.
The .so file is placed in a folder in my package called /thirdparty.
This is how I have linked the .so file in the CMakelists.txt file:

```
if (CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR STREQUAL "aarch64")
  find_library(libCubeEye NAMES libCubeEye.so HINTS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/aarch64/libcubeeye/lib/)
elseif(CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR STREQUAL "x86_64")
  if(UNIX)
    find_library(libCubeEye NAMES libCubeEye.so HINTS ${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/thirdparty/x86_64/libcubeeye/lib)
  endif(UNIX)
endif()

if (NOT libCubeEye)
  message(FATAL_ERROR "libCubeEye library not found")
endif()

#ament_export_targets(libCubeEye HAS_LIBRARY_TARGET)

include_directories(
  ${OpenCV_INCLUDE_DIRS}
  thirdparty/${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}/libcubeeye/include
  thirdparty/${CMAKE_HOST_SYSTEM_PROCESSOR}/onnxruntime-linux-x64-1.15.1/include
)
```

It builds without issues but as soon as I run my node, I get the following error:

> /home/victor/ros2_ws/install/cpp_inference_client/lib/cpp_inference_client/infernce_client: error while loading shared libraries: libCubeEye.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
> [ros2run]: Process exited with failure 127

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following

```
find_library(MYLIB test_lib.so)

add_executable(test main.c)

target_link_libraries(test MYLIB)
```

https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html